# Unity 2021.3.0f Builds getting stuck if run build from terminal

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a custom build pipeline. In Unity 2020 and 2019 version all works fine. After switching to version 2021.3.0f my build started to infinity loading. I use this bash command to start build process `/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.0f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -batchmode -logfile -buildTarget iOS -executeMethod AutoBuilder.PerformiOSBuild -projectPath "project path" -serial $UNITY_ACCOUNT_SERIAL -username $UNITY_ACCOUNT_USERNAME -password $UNITY_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD`

Build script code below

```
static async void PerformiOSBuild()
    {
        await Task.Delay(15 * 1000);
        PlayerSettings.iOS.sdkVersion = iOSSdkVersion.DeviceSDK;
        EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(BuildTargetGroup.iOS, BuildTarget.iOS);
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(EditorBuildSettings.scenes, "Builds/iOS", BuildTarget.iOS, BuildOptions.SymlinkSources);

        EditorApplication.Exit(0); // We cant use "-quit" cli option  with async methods so we quite manually
    }
```

Last lines of logs

```
[Licensing::Module] Successfully updated access token: "y4LfqSkH"... (expires: 2022-04-21 17:37:28 GMT)
User "email" logged in successfully
[collab-accelerator] discovery started due to a new cloud project binding
UPID Received 'b6ada6db-b20a-4291-a033-cd2866b3d279'.
[collab-accelerator] Set collab endpoint to https://collab.cloud.unity3d.com (collab-service)
```

If i run build script manually from unity, it's works fine. I have no idea what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to delete await operation from build script. In unknown reason unity 2021.3.0 not support await operation in build method called from batchmode.